# Continuous functions and open sets

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm working on a proof and having trouble applying a certain theorem.

I want to prove that if $ f $ is a continuous function from a metric space into the real numbers, then the set $ {f(x)>0} $ (where $ x $ is a point in the metric space) is open. I'm thinking the best way to prove this is to use the following theorem: A mapping $ f $ of a metric space $ X $ into another metric space $ Y $ is continuous on $ X $ if and only if $ f^-(V) $ is open in $ X $ for every open set $ V $ in $ Y $. Is this a good idea?

Comment: This is a very good idea. Now you should try to find $V$ in $\mathbbm{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(V)=\{x\mid f(x)>0\}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you are trying to prove that the set $\{x\in X\,|\, f(x) > 0\}$ is open?

In this case, yes. The above set is just $f^{-1}(]0,\infty[)$; but $]0,\infty[$ is open in **R**, so as $f$ is a continuous mapping, $f^{-1}(]0,\infty[)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: why is the above set $f^-(0,infiniti)$?

Comment: Because an element u of X is in f^-1(]0,infinity[) if and only if f(u) is in ]0,infinity[, that's if and only if f(u) > 0.

Answer (score 0):

The one you wrote is a characterisation of continous function, and it's a good choice.

Since $f:(X,d_X)\to(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$ is a continous function between metric spaces, and $]0,+\infty[$ is open in $\Bbb R$ (with euclidean metric, which induces euclidean topology, in this way, speaking of *open sets* makes sense) then
$$
\{x\in X\;:\;f(x)>0\}=f^{-1}(]0,+\infty[)
$$
by the theorem you cited, is open.

Comment: is $ ]0,+\infty[ $ a way to write the interval between $ 0 $ and $ +\infty $ not including $ 0 $?

Comment: @Restyla:yes it is.

Comment: okay thanks joe